# java stores number in file and will replace number with greater number but won't store if file is empty

Tags: java, file-io, readfile

I've tried the file.length code to scan file and if it's empty it will store the new number. However, it won't store it in the file if the file is empty. But it will replace the number in the file if the new number is greater. I'm trying to get it to store the first number in the file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt(); 
        reader.close();

        File file = new File("number.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int a = input.nextInt();

        if (n > a){
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(n);
            output.close();
        } else if (file.length() == 0){
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(n);
            output.close();
        }else { 
           System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have optimized your code.

First, you should mention the directory of `number.txt` file, in my case, it's created in the package `test`, so I mentioned `src/test/number.txt`.

Then, I have assigned `null` value to `PrintWriter` class in order to  use later inside `if` statements.

`Scanner input = new Scanner(file);` in this case, you should not need to use a second `Scanner` class if you do not need any input from console, it depends on you.

`while` loop checks if your file is empty or not, if empty, `int a` is zero, else, `int a` gets the number from file. The rest of the code equals your code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        File file = new File("src/test/number.txt");
        PrintWriter output = null;

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = reader.nextInt();

        //you do not need to use a second Scanner class if you do not need any input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        int a = 0;

        //this is for reading a number of "number.txt" file
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            a = input.nextInt();
        }

        if (n > a) {
            output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(n);
            output.close();
        } else if (file.length() == 0) {
            output = new PrintWriter(file);
            output.println(n);
            output.close();
        } else {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
        }
    }
}
```